# Bypassing DNS server to request domain from specific server

Tags: php, apache, redirect, dns

I have a special situation that is outside my area of expertise, being a PHP developer and not a network administrator.

A client wants to do split testing between the new website I built them, and their old website built by a competitor. All traffic will be sent to the existing url (a.com). I have access to the client's godaddy account for a.com, and traffic is sent via an A-Record to a server that I *do not* have access to. The old webmaster will not do anything to help my cause, understandably.

Thus, I believe I need to change the a-record on the domain to point to my own server. But how will I send 50% of traffic to the old server? If I navigate to the IP Address on the A-Record directly the website doesn't come up, I presume because the server only knows to use the vhost if the request comes in as a.com. So, I need to change the a-record, then send traffic to this IP address requesting this server....and I need to do this for 50% of the hits I receive. I'm not sure if I can do this using php header()...I'm not sure how to do this at all.

Any recommendations are welcome...I'm racking my brain but can't find a solution.

Comment: this should be doable with [Apaches load balancing](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html). change the record so all traffic goes to your site then balance of 50% to the original IP

Comment: Since your new website is being tested, wouldn't it be better to create a different domain and test it separately (b.com)? Having 50% of all the traffic going randomly to two *different* websites sounds not only weird but also potentially dangerous (dns caching, session management). This way you would have total control of the web server.

Comment: DNS based load balancing won't work very well for any session related code or sites that would otherwise benefit from having a consistent interface per session; you have to pull some tricks to make it work.

Comment: Thank you very much for the responses. This is a special situation, creating a second URL would be fine, but all traffic is going to start at the existing url...they've already bough advertising. Load Balancing sounds like the right solution if this were going to be a higher trafficked site or a permanent solution, but since it's neither of these things I'm going to give Round Robin DNS a shot, and fall back to load balancing if this for some reason doesn't work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get DNS moved to a server you have access to. DNS Round Robbin may be a crude method to achieve this.  Setting up 2 a records, one for each server will automatically alternate as the domain is resolved. I've not tried this with completly different content on the 2 servers but it may be worth testing

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone. I've read up on Round Robin DNS and it does sound like a simple (although crude) method for handling this situation. I was unaware that simply entering two @ a records would send alternating hits to one server or the other, very handy to know.

Answer (score 1):

Are any users hitting your version of the website?

IF you have access to the a records, you can actually add two a records.

```
@ IP1
@ IP2
```

And let DNS do it's thing.

**EDIT**

or as the other user said, apache load handling can do the trick